# How to send upnp request using curl

Tags: linux, port-forwarding, upnp

I'm trying to find a way to add port forward using UPnP,I did turned on upnp and I can access `http://192.168.1.254:52869/gateconnSCPD.xml` that mena that upnp service is on, but I can't get [miranda](http://tools.kali.org/information-gathering/miranda) to actualy find upnp server using discovery, it seams that that part actualy is not working. I did find on net example of request but that also not workig

```
curl 'http://192.168.1.254:52869/Public_UPNP_C3' \
  -X 'POST' \
  -H 'Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"' \
  -H 'Connection: close' \
  -H 'SOAPAction: "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:WANIPConnection:1#AddPortMapping"' \
  -d '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<s:Body>
<u:AddPortMapping xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:WANIPConnection:1">
  <NewRemoteHost></NewRemoteHost>
  <NewExternalPort>27015</NewExternalPort>
  <NewProtocol>TCP</NewProtocol>
  <NewInternalPort>27015</NewInternalPort>
  <NewInternalClient>192.168.1.2</NewInternalClient>
  <NewEnabled>1</NewEnabled>
  <NewPortMappingDescription>node:nat:upnp</NewPortMappingDescription>
  <NewLeaseDuration>10</NewLeaseDuration>
</u:AddPortMapping>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>'
```

Is there "simple" request which can open port forward over upnp ?

Comment: It sounds in general that something in your UPnP setup is not working as it should, but there's not enough information to find out. If the UPnP setup on the router is working, you can e.g. use `upnpc` from the `miniupnpc` to add a port forwarding to your router. I'm not even sure it it's possible to do that with `curl` and handcrafted requests.

Comment: TNX I tried upnpc but Im getting error 
    GetExternalIPAddress failed. (errorcode=399)

Comment: are you trying upnpc from the source host?

Comment: No I did not will chek it tnx

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a very old issue, but since I was lately playing with this, I thought I should post the answer here for others.

The header field "Content-Length: " is required, and should include the length of your data field, otherwise it fails.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).